# SUM quantity of products that belong to the same group (group_id)

Tags: mysql

I have a product catalog, each product have 2 quantities (products_quantity and products_incoming_quantity), some products are grouped together under group_id.

I'm trying to give the products that belong to the same group the same quantity, which is the Total of all quantities.

I tried to use GROUP_BY, but I have difficulty writing the mysql code because group_id is in another table.

products table :

```
|-------------|---------------|-------------------|----------------------------|
| products_id | products_name | products_quantity | products_incoming_quantity |
|-------------|---------------|-------------------|----------------------------|
|      10     |   Product A   |         05        |             02             |
|-------------|---------------|-------------------|----------------------------|
|      11     |   Product B   |         15        |             08             |
|-------------|---------------|-------------------|----------------------------|
|      12     |   Product C   |         12        |             00             |
|-------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------------
```

products to group table

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|     products_id     |     Group_ID      | 
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          10         |         01        |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          11         |         01        |
|---------------------|-------------------|
```

query :

```
$listing_sql = "select 
    p.products_id, 
    p.products_quantity, p.products_incoming_quantity, 
    (p.products_quantity + p.products_incoming_quantity) AS sub_quantity,
    g.products_id,
    g.group_id      
    FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " WHERE
    p.products_id = g.products_id";
```

I'm trying to add new field "total_quantity" to output the quantity value as this :

Product A total_quantity = 30
Product B total_quantity = 30

Same quantity because they belong to same group.

I need some help to create this query.

Thanks :)

Comment: One question: can the same product be in multiple groups?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Psi No the same product cannot be selected again to be inserted in the same or another group.

Comment: Why is it in a different table then? Just put it as an additional column to the products table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im trying to store the SUM of sub_quantity, of products of the same group_id, as total_quantity. 
e.g. 
Product A total_quantity = 30 and Product B total_quantity = 30

Comment: @Psi currently that's how it is written, and tables are filled with data. If it's impossible to resolve, I will change code and migrate data.

Comment: That's not impossible, I just asked why it was laid out that way. Maybe there was a good reason for that. You can simply solve this by joining.

Comment: @Psytanium Your expected numbers do not add up at all, and _don't_ match the data you gave.  Please add the expected result, if you want an answer here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I'm not sure how I should explain the expected output, but I will try. Total_quantity of Product A = 30 the result of (5 + 2 + 15 + 8), the same goes for Product B, because A and B belong to the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may join to a subquery which aggregates by group and finds the total quantities:

```
SELECT
    p.products_id,
    p.products_quantity,
    p.products_incoming_quantity,
    (p.products_quantity + p.products_incoming_quantity) AS sub_quantity,
    t.total_quantity,
    g.products_id,
    g.group_id,
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_groups g
    ON p.products_id = g.products_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        g.group_ID,
        SUM(p.products_quantity + p.products_incoming_quantity) AS total_quantity
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN product_groups g
        ON p.products_id = g.products_id
    GROUP BY g.group_ID
) t
    ON g.group_id = t.group_id;
```

Note that I converted your query syntax to use explicit inner joins, instead of old school comma based implicit joins.  The way I wrote your query is the preferred way of writing it in modern times.

If you were using MySQL 8+ or later, we might be able to simplify using analytic functions.